Movie about boy learning from old man
At least I think it was a movie.
A boy must go over to a man's house and type on a typewriter and ends up learning from the old man. 
I remember one part in particular where the old man asks the boy to stir the soup before it forms a skin. The boy asks why the old man's soup forms a skin. The old man tells him it's the milk in his soup and the boy's mother probably doesn't have enough money to put milk in her soup. I know it's an inconsequential scene, but it really sticks in my head. 
Sorry about the lack of detail. I'm really having trouble remembering...

Possible duplicate of A student who plays basketball but likes to read
